# Filter rows based on a ID column in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, data-transform

I have a data frame with an ID column, Timepoint and status. Each ID has multiple timepoints and status associated with each timepoint. I want to filter all the ID's which has the same status for all timepoints associated with the ID. How can I achieve that  with R dpylr ?

Below is a sample dataset

| ID | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | X |
| A | 2 | X |
| A | 3 | Y |
| A | 4 | Z |
| B | 1 | X |
| B | 2 | X |
| B | 3 | X |
| C | 1 | Z |
| C | 2 | Z |
| D | 1 | X |
| E | 1 | X |
| E | 2 | Y |

Expected Dataframe

| ID | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | X |
| B | 2 | X |
| B | 3 | X |
| C | 1 | Z |
| C | 2 | Z |
| D | 1 | X |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(length(unique(Status)) == 1)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID     Time Status
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 B         1 X     
2 B         2 X     
3 B         3 X     
4 C         1 Z     
5 C         2 Z     
6 D         1 X
```

Comment: You could simplify this more by using `dplyr::n_distinct()` instead of `length(unique(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(Status)==1], ID]
```